# Variance and Standard Deviation

Tags: probability

A fair six-sided die carries $1$ on one face, $2$ on two of its faces, and
$3$ on the remaining three faces.

Suppose the die is rolled twice, and let $X$ be the random variable ’total score'. Find the probability distribution of $X$.

Comment: You are expected to show some of your own work.  What have you tried so far, and what is causing you trouble?

Comment: Getting the probability distribution is the major problem here.But finding the variance and mean is not a problem

Comment: Why is it a problem?  You have a support of only five values whose probability mass is readily apparent.

Comment: I dont know how to distribute its probability mass

Comment: Well, what is $\mathsf P(T=t)$ for each $t\in\{2,3,4,5,6\}$?  That is it.

Comment: what about their probabilities?? and I think  t∈{2,3,4,5,6} should be t∈{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}

Comment: $T$ is the score of rolling $\{1,2,3\}$ twice, so how would this give a sum of more than $6$?  One each roll, these sides may occur with the indicated probability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The six-sided die has `1` on one face, `2` on two faces, and `3` on three faces.   That gives the support and priobabilities for an individual roll.

The die is rolled twice, and the result of each roll added to give $T$.   Thus let $T=T_1+T_2$, with $T_1,T_2$ being the individual die rolls, which are independent and identically distributed as above.

$$\therefore\qquad \mathsf P(T{=}t) ~=~\sum_{s=\max\{1,\,t-3\}}^{\min\{3,\,t-1\}} \mathsf P(T_1{=}s)\,\mathsf P(T_2{=}t{-}s) ~\mathbf 1_{t\in\{2,3,4,5,6\}}$$

Answer (score 1):

For example, $P(T=2)$ is the probability that we get $1$ at both tries. Since the trials are independent, this means:

$P(T=2) = P(1~on~first~try)\times P(1~on~second~try)=1/6\times 1/6=1/36$.
You can work through all other situations as it is suggested.